# How to get previous slide index in slick slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I am using the slick slider for my slides now I would like to get the previous slide index, I know how to get clicked slide index as follows

```
$('.carousel').on('afterChange', function() {
    var dataId = $('.slick-current').attr("data-slick-index");    
    console.log(dataId);
});
```

so how do I get the previous slide index using  Jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Slick Event documentation](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#events) the `afterChange` event accepts a `currentSlide` argument which is an integer value which is the index of the current slide. To get the index of the previous slide, subtract 1 from this value:

```
$('.carousel').on('afterChange', function(e, s, currentSlideIndex) {
  let previousSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex - 1;  
  console.log(previousSlideIndex);
});
```

Comment: check the thread here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285061/go-back-to-the-prevoius-slide-using-slick-and-jquery

Comment: this is wrong answer. the carousel can be swiped from the left or use navigation page (1,2,3,4) to jump. use currentSlideIndex only gets the slide positioned immediately before it, not the slide previously showed.

Answer (score -1):

the answer provided is wrong. should just use cached variable from

```
.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {}
```