# Go back to the prevoius slide using slick and jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I have slides that contain multiple calls to actions which open different slide on click

eg if a user is in slide **number 1** and clicks a button which opens slide number 5, on clicking button **go back** it should go back to slide **number 1**

Here is : [LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/makumba/pen/yLbOPya)

HTML

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="slider carousel">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>

  <div class="action">
    <a id="slide_3" href="#" data-slide="3">go to slide 3</a>
    <a id="slide_4" href="#" data-slide="4">go to slide 4</a>
    <a id="slide_5" href="#" data-slide="5">go to slide 5</a>    
    <a id="go-back" href="#" data-slide="5">GO BACK</a>
        
  </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
var sliderIndex = 0;

$('.carousel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
});

$("#slide_3").click(function() {
    $(".carousel").slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(2));
})

$("#slide_4").click(function() {
    $(".carousel").slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(3));
})

$("#slide_5").click(function() {
    $(".carousel").slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(4));
})

$('.carousel').on('afterChange', function(e, s, currentSlideIndex) {
    sliderIndex = currentSlideIndex-1;

});


$("#go-back").click(function() {

    $(".carousel").slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(sliderIndex));

})
```

> Problem: assume I am in slide number 5 Now when I click go to slide 3
> and click go back instead of going back to slide number 5 it will go
> to slide number 2

Comment: Why is there a go back, go back to what? Just click button one again.

Comment: @Grumpy that is a sample I have multiple slides this will open different slides with a different button? I made it simple so that u can understand

Comment: There should be a previous and next button, not 2 3 5, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button `Go Back` in your code just goes back to previous index of current slide. e.g. if current slide is n, it will just go back to n - 1.
If you want `Go Back` to go back to previous slide that you clicked, you should keep track of current as well as previous index.

Please refer below code -

```js
var currentSliderIndex = 0;
var previousSliderIndex = 0;

$('.carousel').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: false,
   fade: true,
 });
 
$("#slide_3").click(function(){
  $(".carousel").slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(2));
})

$("#slide_4").click(function(){
  $(".carousel").slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(3));
})

$("#slide_5").click(function(){
  $(".carousel").slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(4));
})

$('.carousel').on('afterChange', function (e, s, currentSlideIndex) {
                                previousSliderIndex = currentSliderIndex
                currentSliderIndex = currentSlideIndex;
 
        });


         $("#go-back").click(function () {
                    $(".carousel").slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(previousSliderIndex));
                   
                })
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.main {
  font-family:Arial;
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
h3 {
    background: #fff;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.action{
  display:block;
  margin:100px auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.action a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px; 
  background:#f30;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.action a:hover{
  background:#000;
}

#go-back{
      background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="slider carousel">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>

  <div class="action">
    <a id="slide_3" href="#" data-slide="3">go to slide 3</a>
    <a id="slide_4" href="#" data-slide="4">go to slide 4</a>
    <a id="slide_5" href="#" data-slide="5">go to slide 5</a>    
    <a id="go-back" href="#" data-slide="5">GO BACK</a>
        
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note - This will only keep track of a single previous slide, if you click back multiple times, it will just keep shuffling between 2 slides.